# Python Pandas: How to update values for other column in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with time series.

```
    meter   date    value
0   1002    19501   0.362
1   1002    19502   0.064
2   1002    19503   0.119
3   1002    19504   0.023
4   1002    19505   0.140
```

Now I need to change the date to numeric order (1,2,3, etc. until 336) for each unique value in meter. There 336 rows for each unique meter value, so that shouldn't be too difficult, but I am stuck at getting the right result here.

I tried the following:

```
def change_timestamp(df):
  timestamp_uniform = [i for i in range(1,337)]
  timestamp = pd.Series(data=timestamp_uniform)
  df.date = timestamp.values
  return df.date

by_meter = meters_weekly.groupby('meter')
by_meter.apply(change_timestamp)
```

but the output was just dates repeated.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: how do you want to summarize you `value` data?

Comment: I don't need to summarize it, I have to keep it as-is. I just need to update the "date" feature to 1,2,3...n for the length of that meter ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this -

```
df['new_date'] = df.groupby(['meter']).cumcount()
```